# SQL query for max(price) article per supplier. Can't understand the logic behind

Tags: sql

This query select a list with the name and price of the most expensive articles by supplier, incluiding the provider name.

The tables are just:

Supplier:  Code(PK) - Name

Articles: Code (PK) - Name - Price - Supplier (FK)

And the query is:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.PRICE, S.NAME FROM ARTICLES A, SUPPLIERS S 
WHERE A.SUPPLIER = S.CODE
AND A.PRICE = 
(
SELECT MAX(A.PRICE) 
FROM ARTICLES A 
WHERE A.SUPPLIER = S.CODE
)
```

Would you please help me understand the logic behind? Why does this give me the max price PER SUPPLIER?

Thank you!

Comment: I have answered your question below, but it might pay to provide sample data with sample results as well as expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You inner query is getting the maximum price for a subset of articles - those that match the supplier.code passed in from the outer query. So the inner query says, "give me the highest price for supplier X."

The outer query is filtering the joined list to only provide those records that have match on the results from the inner query - those that happen to equal the highest price. It will match multiple records in the outer list if more than one record equates to the highest price for the supplier.

Comment: Thanks Alan! What I don´t get is why this inner query works.

Comment: Ah! That's what's referred to as a correlated subquery. Read up on them and you will add an important weapon to your arsenal.  The inner query, like a subclass, is aware of the fields in the outer query. It is important to provide namespace prefixes carefully for this reason or you can end up with some unintended joins.